# Cómo agregar dentro de Laravel (Blade) <a href = '{{route (' ')}}

Tags: laravel-5, datatables, laravel-blade, rutas

Hola tengo un problema con las rutas

tengo mi ruta:

```
Route::get('usuario/{id}/edit', ['as' => 'users.edit', 'uses' => 'Admin\UserController@edit']);
```

y desde mi datatables tengo una columna donde creo un boton

```
{data: null, render: function (data, type, row) {
    return '<a href="{{ route('users.edit', $user->id) }}"  class="btn btn-xs btn-primary" ><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></i></a>';
 }
}
```

Asi siempre me muestra el id 1

en cambio si utilizo

```
return '<a href="users.edit/' + data.id + '"  class="btn btn-xs btn-primary" ><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></i></a>';
```

si me cambia a los id corectos pero mi ruta ya no funciona

Comment: `$user->id` y esto si cambia antes de llamarlo en el return donde utilizas route?

Comment: documentación oficial (5.4) `Si la ruta acepta parámetros, puede pasarlos como el segundo argumento del método: $url = route('routeName', ['id' => 1]);` en tu caso debería ser `route('users.edit', ['id' => $user->id])`